# Proving Zero Object as Kernel of Monomorphism in Abelian Categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Recently I delved into category theory, and I would appreciate some help with a proof I'm currently stuck on.

lets say $C$ is an abelian category, and $f:A \to B$ is a monomorphism.
I came across a statement suggesting that it's possible to prove that the $zero$ $object$ (lets call it $0$) together with it unique map $0 \to A$, can serve as the kernel of $f$.

So, before proving universality of this kernel, I suppose to show that the composition of $0 \to A \to B$ (where $f$ is the morphism between $A$ and $B$) is in fact the zero morphism. How can i show that?
I know that between every two objects $X,Y \in C$ there exist and unique a "zero morphism" $X \to 0 \to Y$, but how can i derive that $0 \to A \to B$ is also a zero morphism?

Proving universality make more sense to me, cause for every $g:X \to A$ such that $f*g=0$ we have the unique morphism $u: X \to 0$, and because f is $monic$ we get the right equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to note that $0\to A\to B =0 \to B$ by definition of zero object (it is the only morphism from 0 to B).
The fact that this is in fact the zero morphism from $0$ to $B$ is true since you can clearly write $0\to B=0\to 0\to B$, which is in fact the definition of the zero morphism (note that this does not depend on the fact that $f$ is a monomorphism).

Comment: Thank you! thats important to note. But hows that imply that $0 \to B$ is the zero morphism ?(to basically show that 0 is the kernel of $f$)

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading your question with more attention. What do you mean by saying that $0\to A$ can serve as the kernel of $f$?

Comment: a kenrel of $f:A \to B$ consist of an object $ker(f)$ together with a morphism $k:ker(f) \to A$ such that $f*k=0$ and $ker(f)$ have universality. im trying to prove that the kernel of a monomorphism can be the zero object together with it unique morphism from itself to A (meaning $0 \to A$). so for the start, i need to show that $0 \to A \to B$ equal zero morphism, and im not really sure how to show that.

Comment: thank you for the edit, but i just want to point that my question is only asking about monomorphism (not a general morphism)

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I noticed later.
You have that $0\to A\to B$ is the zero morphism from $0$ to $B$ by definition, since you can obviously write $0\to A\to B=0\to B=0\to 0\to B$ which in fact is the zero morphism **from $0$ to $B$**

Comment: thanks a lot! :)